# Find the sum of first 99 terms of the sequence defined by $T_{n}=\frac{1}{5^{2n-100}+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Find the sum of first $99$ terms of a sequence, where $$T_{n}=\frac{1}{5^{2n-100}+1}.$$

I need some hints on how to approach; I am unable to simplify it. Thanks.

Comment: $T_1 + T_{99} = ?$, $T_2 + T_{98} = ?,\ldots$.

Comment: You got **the** hint !

Comment: It is trivial once you got achille's hint. Try to do it yourself now.

Comment: I don't know if I'd have spotted that symmetry by staring at it. There's a heuristic point here about writing out the first few and last few terms in such problems...

Comment: @AmpleMimic There are not too many tricks to create hard looking but actually easy to solve problem. One is symmetry like this, the other one is some sort of telescoping. If a homework type problem looks very hard, then the first thing one should do is see whether one of these tricks has been used.

Answer (score 5):

Paying attention carefully given first to me $T_{50-n}=5^{2n}T_{50+n}$ from which some properties emerge. However much better is $T_n+T_{100-n}=1$ and $T_{50} = \frac12$ from which the solution is immediate. We have
$T_1+T_2+T_3+…….+T_{49}+ \frac12 +T_{51}+T_{52}+…..T_{98}+T_{99} $
from  where, rearranging terms, we get $\sum_{n=1}^{n=49}(T_n+T_{100-n}) =49$
Thus the answer is $49+\frac12=\frac{99}{2}$